# \subsection without \section is numbered 0.1. How do I make it 1.1 without the \section?

Tags: setcounter

I'm using  \documentclass{amsbook}

I'll grant it's a little unusual but I'd like to open a chapter with a series of subsections, but without a section. When I do this I get the numbering noted in the question:

0.1 A Subsection.

Which I would like to be 1.1 A Subsection.

There were several teasingly close Q&As here that I've read and from them I figured the answer would be to reset the section counter. So I tried \setcounter{section}{1}

I got: 0.2 A subsection, which doesn't make any sense to me assuming that the numbering goes section#.subsection#. So, I clearly don't understand the mechanics.

Any help?

EDIT: Includes code and screen shot.

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}%
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what do you number the first `\subsection` within a regular section? So you'll have `1.1 Subsection.` as the first subsection in some chapter, and then later `1.1 Subsection.` as the first subsection in the first section?

Comment: works as expected for me. `\chapter{xxx}\setcounter{section}{1}\subsection{yyy}` gives 1.1. yyy in amsbook.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Apologies, I thought this was so simple it wouldn't need the code. I'll edit to include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Weird. See my edits including screen shot.

Comment: @TonyK: You should use `\setcounter{section}{1}`, not `\setcounter{subsection}{1}`.

Comment: @Werner. I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. In any event, Mr. Carlisle may be right that I should have included a minimal doc. See the edited post.

Comment: you said you did \setcounter{section}{1} you show \setcounter{subsection}{1}

Comment: @Werner: section not subsection Duh! Thank you. My stupid mistake.  I really should let a few hours pass before I fire off a question. Apologies to all for being a nuisance.

Comment: @TonyK: So how do you reference/compare the first subsection `1.1 Subsection.` that doesn't occur in a section and the first subsection `1.1 Subsection` that does occur under the first section?

Comment: Why are you trying to confuse your readers?  As you say, the logical order is `chapter`, `section`,`subsection`. Is it that you prefer the look of `subsection` to `section`? Logically a `subsection` must be a sub of a `section`. Please don't confuse the logical structure of a document with it's printed appearance . Admittedy they should be the same so as tot to confuse your readers.

Comment: @Werner: I guess I don't expect to reference the content. It is a very short chapter and I really had nothing useful to say in a section by way of introduction to the sequence of subsections. I suppose I could make the subsections sections, but each is very short. I'll give the structure some more thought.

Comment: @PeterWilson. It seems I've opened a can of worms here by "messing" with the logical structure. And I agree it is logical. I suspect that I will be the only soul in the universe ever to read this book, but just in case it escapes to the wild I commit to trying to rework it to respect the structure. I owe at least that much to the community that has been so helpful.

Comment: @TonyK: You can also use **unnumbered** sectional units (like `\subsection*`, say) to delineate the content (it'll have the same formatting as the numbered level) and then don't have to worry about the numbering being confusing to the end user/reader.

Comment: @Werner. That might work -- I'll noodle with it and see what it looks like in context. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Once again I forgot to uptick helpful comments. Taken care of now. Apologies for being a laggard.